# Indefinate Pagination with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I'm trying to create pagination links at the bottom, but right now it's listing every single page instead of five links at a time. I'd like it to just display five page links with arrows. Here's what i have so far:

```
            <!-- Pagination -->
        <div class="pagination-centered">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <?php 
                $p = $maxPage;
                $end = ceil($pageNo / $p) * $p;
                $start = $end - $p + 1;
                if($maxPage < $end){
                    $end = $maxPage;
                }
                ?>

                <?php if($pageNo > $start){?>                   
                <li class="arrow"><a href="?page=<?php echo $pageNo - 1; ?>">&laquo;</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                    $pi = $start;
                    $pNo = $pageNo;
                    while ($pi<=$end) {
                        if($pi == $pageNo){
                            echo '<li class="current"><a href="">'. $pi . '</a></li>';
                        } else {
                        ?>

                        <li><a href="?page=<?php echo $pi; ?>"><?php echo $pi ; ?></a></li>

                <?php   
                       } 
                       $pi++;
                   } 
                ?>
                <?php if($pageNo < $end){ ?>
                    <li class="arrow">
                        <a href="?page=<?php echo $pageNo + 1; ?>">&raquo;</a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>

                <!--?php
                    $pNo = $pageNo;
                    $maxPno = $pNo + 5;
                    while ($pNo<=$maxPage && $pNo<=$maxPno) {
                        if($pNo == $pageNo){
                            echo '<li class="current"><a href="">'. $pNo . '</a></li>';
                        } else {
                        ?>

                        <li><a href="?page=<?php echo $pNo; ?>"><?php echo $pNo; ?></a></li-->

                <!--?php   
                       } 
                       $pNo++;
                   } 
                ?-->


            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- END Pagination -->
```

Any help on this would be much appriciated. Also, I don't want it to issue a get call after every click, because the database could be quite large. And, I don't know how many pages it will eventually have as I expect the database to be added to. Further, I did create a JSON file that pulls the relevant data that can be used to create these links.

Comment: Is `<!--?php` being purposely commented out?

Comment: Plus, you tagged this as `jquery`, why? There is none in your question/code.

Comment: `$end = ceil($pageNo / $p) * $p;` What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the page buttons in a for loop like this:

```
for($i = $current_page - 2; $i < $current_page; $i++){
    if($i > 0){
        echo "<a href='./?page=$i'>$i</a>";
    }
}
echo "<a class="current_page">$i</a>";
for($i = $current_page + 1; $i <= $current_page + 2; $i++){
    if($i <= $last_page){
        echo "<a href='./?page=$i'>$i</a>";
    }
}
```